# php $_POST problems

Tags: php, post

Ok, I know this is probably a really dumb question but I can't figure out what is going on here. I've got this in my original html file-

```
<form action="./api" method="POST">
    <label for="first-name">First Name: </label>
    <input id="first-name" type="text" name="first_name" /><br/>
    <label for="last-name">Last Name: </label>
    <input id="last-name" type="text" name="last_name" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
```

In my api folder I have an index.php file that has the following code-

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Thats it- I know its not safe but I was just trying to get it to work. It returns an empty array...

```
Array ()
```

I really need a second pair of eyes on this, what am I missing? why isn't the information being transmitted?

---

Update:

changing the action to action="./api/index.php" returns the posted variables as expected. As someone commented below, I was hitting the index.php in the api folder before because it was returning the empty array. Its strange that it didn't accept the data. Is it common practice in php then to make the target of your post explicit?

Comment: looks ok, how about both files in same directory?

Comment: Your form action most probably needs to be "index.php" instead of "./api" assuming it's located in the same folder. I don't think you are triggering it well.

Comment: Maybe some "creative" url rewriting is done?

Comment: Is it possible that you have print_r($_POST) in the same file as that form and you are expecting it to have a value *before* the user submits the form? I've seen that happen many times.

Comment: Asking the obvious here: have you tried starting at the form and submitting it again? (If your code has changed recently, you may not have been POSTing properly before.) Do you have any .htaccess files? What happens if you do `action="api/index.php"`?

Comment: is `index.php` set to be your default document?

Comment: Also, please confirm whether you're doing a straight-up submission manually or using any JavaScript.

Comment: I think everyone is overlooking the fact that they state it returns `Array ()`, so it is hitting index.php

Comment: action="api/index.php" seems to make it work- what is causing it to not work with simply pointing to the directory?

Comment: @James Yes, but bad things could happen if there are any URL rewrites first.

Comment: @Jimbo It's probably a URL rewrite or a redirect. It's hard to know for sure without more information.

Comment: @Jimbo If you are using IIS, it is known to lose post data when doing IIS rewrites.

Comment: I'm using xampp with apache

Comment: You don't need to update the question to explain the problem. Accepting the answer implies that the answer solved the problem.

Comment: @Barmar- the answer wasn't there when I updated my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the full file path to your action and convert your
`$_POST['']` to variables. The code below should work perfectly based on your question.

```
 <form action="../api/index.php" method="POST">
        <label for="first-name">First Name: </label>
        <input id="first-name" type="text" name="first_name" /><br/>
        <label for="last-name">Last Name: </label>
        <input id="last-name" type="text" name="last_name" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>
```

Add this to ../api/index.php

```
 <?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
echo $first_name;
echo $last_name;
?>
```